# Construction of a polynomial within a region

Tags: calculus, polynomials

Let $P$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ with real coefficients, such that $P(9)=0$  and $P(10)=13$. If $x\in[0,9]$ then $P(x) \in [-9,0]$. Find the minimum $n$

Comment: where are you stuck?

Comment: One could try to take $n$ starting from $n=0$ and show that this $n$ is impossible until some $n$ becomes possible.

Comment: I suppose $P(x)=13(x-9)+(x-9)(x-10)Q(x)$ may help, but I'm not sure.